# How can we get notification of Facebook App settings , graph API and Real time update changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For example,

Facebook Dashboard 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/21/bringing-real-time-updates-to-the-app-dashboard/

I can't seem to find these settings for realtime updates anymore with the new update to the App Dashboard.

Is this possible to get notify via email or any other ?

Thank you.